# Узнать путь файла на сервере

Tags: java, servlet, fileupload

Всем добрый день, вот назрела такая проблема:
Я загружаю текстовый файл на сервер и мне нужно из этого файла вытащить инфу(поиск слова, метаданные), но как мне узнать путь этого файла, с тем условием, что имя текстового файла может быть любым.
Загружаю с помощью FileUpload, а другой метод должен подхватить этот файл:

```
    new FileReader(new File("$TOMCAT_HOME\\webapps\\ROOT\\uploadFiles\\Text.txt"))
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: О каком именно FileUpload речь?

Comment: Nofate, о Commons FileUpload

Comment: Разве Вы не сами задаёте путь к файлу, куда его upload-ить?

Comment: да, верно, но проблема в том, что я не знаю заранее его имя.

Comment: @Dmitry уточните каким образом используется fileupload. Возможны варианты. В самом примитивном `File file = ((DiskFileItem)item).getStorageLocation();`

Comment: @banme, таким способом http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-file-upload-example-with-servlet-30-api

Comment: @Dmitry но там commons fileupload не используется. Только упоминается, что раньше им приходилось пользоваться. По новой методе самостоятельно формируется полное имя файла, куда сохраняется upload, включая путь. Т.е. в методе doPost оно известно. В примере это `savePath + File.separator + fileName`. savePath - путь, fileName - имя. Где у Вас вызывается другой, подхватывающий метод, что он теряет всё это?

Comment: @banme, в другом сервлете, в нем и метод

Comment: @banme благодарю за помощь, я просто другим способом теперь загружаю файлы и всё отлично